Issue with Importing `sampler` Module from `hlda` Library in Pytho
I'm working on a project where I need to use the hlda library in Python for hierarchical topic modeling. I installed the hlda library using pip and am trying to import the HierarchicalLDA class from the sampler module within the hlda package.
However, when I try to run the following import statement:
from hlda.sampler import HierarchicalLDA

I get this error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hlda.sampler'; 'hlda' is not a package

I've confirmed that the hlda library is installed, and I can import other modules without any issues. I've also checked the installed hlda package, and the sampler module does exist.

Uninstalling and reinstalling the hlda library.
Verifying the Python environment to ensure everything is installed correctly.
Locating the sampler module within the installed hlda package, and it does exist.

I expected the sampler module to be recognized and the HierarchicalLDA class to be imported without any errors.
Environment:
Python version: 3.10.10.
hlda version: .3.1.
OS: win10.
Pycharm.

It sounds like you are doing everything right so it must be something in the details. Can you edit the question to show how you did the install and verified its installation in the environment

I checked that the hlda package is present in the site-packages directory of my virtual environment.

The issue is with your Python version.
According to PyPi, The stable release of this package i.e. hlda 0.3.1 (which is what you are using) was released on Jan 25, 2021 but Python 3.10 (your Python version) was released on October 4, 2021. It could be that you're having this error due to compatibility issues.
Try downgrading your Python to 3.9. This should fix your errors.
